# Scrollview is not starting at the top, and a grey area at the top

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I'm building a app but the layout is not perfect yet.

I have some problems with the navigationmenu and the scrollview.

First of all the scrollview begin about 20/40 px below the top (see the 2 pictures)

[image]

[image]

Also I see a grey top (see second picture), I think that is te top of the navigationview. Can I work around it?

The code is this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Boxen: View {
    
    // Showing Card Colors on Button Click....
    @State var showColors: Bool = false
    
    // Button Animation...
    @State var animateButton: Bool = false
    
    // MARK: Hover Effect MacOS
    @State var hoverColor: Color = .clear
    
    // MARK: Notes Data
    @StateObject var boxenData: BoxenViewModel = BoxenViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView((boxenData.myBoxen?.isEmpty ?? true) ? .init() : .vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            
            if (boxenData.myBoxen?.isEmpty ?? true){
             
                HeaderView()
                    .padding(.top,isMacOS() ? 25 : 15)
                
                BoxenView()
                    .environmentObject(boxenData)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .center)
            }
            else {

                LazyVStack(spacing: isMacOS() ? 6 : 12, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {

                    Section {
                        BoxenView()
                            .environmentObject(boxenData)
                    } header: {
                        HeaderView()
                            .padding(.top,isMacOS() ? 25 : 15)
                            .background(Color("BG"))
                            .background(Color("BG").frame(height: 100).ignoresSafeArea().offset(y: -80),alignment: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color("BG").ignoresSafeArea())
        .overlay(FAB())
        .popupNavigationView(show: $boxenData.showAddBoxPopup) {
            NewBox()
                .environmentObject(boxenData)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func HeaderView()->some View{
        
        VStack(){
            
            HStack(){
                
                Text("Boxen")
                    .font(isMacOS() ? .system(size: 33, weight: .bold) : .largeTitle.bold())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
                    .modifier(AlertModifier(showAlert: $boxenData.showAlert, alertMsg: $boxenData.alertMsg))
                    
                    // Search Bar...
                    HStack(alignment: .top,spacing: 8){
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 8){
                            
                            TextField("Zoeken", text: $boxenData.searchText)
                            
                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 250,alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.trailing,8)
                
            }
            .padding(.bottom,isMacOS() ? 0 : 10)
            .padding(.leading,isMacOS() ? 25 : 15)
            .padding(.trailing,15)
        
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func FAB()->some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            VStack(spacing: 15){
                
                // Colors...
                let units = ["9","13","15"]
                
                let boxen = boxenData.myBoxen
                let aantal = boxen?.count ?? 0
                let id = String((aantal + 1))
                
                ForEach(units,id: \.self){unit in
                    
                    Text(unit)
                        .padding()
                        .background(
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                                .padding(15)
                                .frame(width: isMacOS() ? 20 : 25, height: isMacOS() ? 20 : 25)
                            )
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation{
                                showColors = false
                                boxenData.boxSizeMeter = unit
                                boxenData.boxIndificatie = id
                                boxenData.boxRowNumber = "0"
                                boxenData.boxPlaceNumber = "0"
                                boxenData.boxLocationPlace = "Oss"
                                boxenData.boxHalLocation = "Onbekend"
                                boxenData.showAddBoxPopup = true
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top,20)
            .frame(height: showColors ? nil : 0)
            .opacity(showColors ? 1 : 0)
            .zIndex(0)
            
            AddButton()
                .zIndex(1)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        .padding()
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func AddButton()->some View{
        Button {
            
            if animateButton{return}
            
            withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0.6)){
                showColors.toggle()
                animateButton.toggle()
            }
            
            // Resetting the button...
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                
                withAnimation(.spring()){
                    animateButton.toggle()
                }
            }
            
        } label: {
            
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .scaleEffect(animateButton ? 1.1 : 1)
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: showColors ? 45 : 0))
                .padding(isMacOS() ? 12 : 15)
                .background(Color.black)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        }
        
        .scaleEffect(animateButton ? 1.1 : 1)
        .padding(.top,30)
    }
}

struct Boxen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Boxen()
    }
}
```

The only navigationview that I have is in the contentview.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("log_status") var log_status: Bool = false
    var body: some View {

        Group{
            if log_status{
                
                NavigationView {
                  List {
                      
                      //Home view
                      NavigationLink(destination: Home(), label: {
                        Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                      })
                      
//                      NavigationLink(destination: Boxen(), label: {
//                        Label("Boxen Locatie", systemImage: "archivebox")
//                      })
                      
                      NavigationLink(destination: Boxen(), label: {
                        Label("Boxen Info", systemImage: "shippingbox")
                      })
                      
                      NavigationLink(destination: Notes(), label: {
                        Label("Mijn Notities", systemImage: "note.text")
                      })
                      
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                    
                      NavigationLink(destination: ContentView().onAppear(){
                          self.logout()
                      }) {
                          Label("Logout", systemImage: "chevron.left.2")
                      }
                  }
                    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                    .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(.columns)
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())

            }
            else{
                
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func logout(){
        do{
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            log_status = false
        }
        catch{
            
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not provided all related code, but it seems you have second NavigationView in details area, which is not needed.

Comment: @Asperi thanks for helping me! I have add the only navigationview in my code. this is in the content view.

Comment: Don’t put the Content View in the Logout Navigation link. It makes 2 instances there fore 2 navigation views

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for helping me. I have changed that, but unfortenly it still not works. I have put the full code above of the view. Can you maybe look at that one. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There is no way to help you anymore, there is too much code and at the same time not enough because we can't reproduce. I can only suggest you start commenting out code from the views, see what causes it so you can adjust.